# Can the Jetson NX use the perf tools (except perf in Linux) to check my code cache misses?

Tags: memcached, embedded-linux, perf, nvidia-jetson, jetson-xavier

At first, Linux for Tegra doesn't support perf tool in Jetson NX, and I have tried using its JP-5.0.1 Driver Package Sources ,but it's still not working...
So maybe there are other tools that can replace the linux perf tool to check the cache misses[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkzM2.png)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3o73.png)